# Why is Tota Konoe No. 7?

Tags: uq-holder

In UQ Holder, when Tota Konoe joined the UQ Holders, he was placed No. 7 and Kurōmaru Tokisaka who joined at the same time as him was placed No. 11. Later on, Santa Sasaki joined and was placed No. 12. So why was Tota Konoe placed No. 7?